# How do i create a heat/zone map in Google Maps for various demographics based on proximity to certain locations?

Tags: google-maps

What and how would be the best way to take a table full of nation wide locations(say locations of a company that provides a service that operates within about 20 miles of its address) and then create a radial zone or heat map of certain demographics or proximities to certain other locations. Like a map that has zones/heats of how many schools are within a 20 miles radius of a certain provided address? I looked into Google Fusion Tables to create polygons but I am having trouble finding a way to relate one address to multiple locations(other than like city, but that only looks at the city, not proximity to that exact location which might be in a suburb outside said city). It would be neat to find a way to have a location with a zone around it highlighting it serviceable radius with the intended markets lit up(heatmap would be cool). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You. can use a voronoi diagram and different color s for different area size.